# How to delete or set null the contents of an Ember object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am using Ember.js for my project, and there is a point when I have to remove all the contents or set every property to `""` or `null` for an `Ember.Object`.

So what is happening is, within the template, there are handlebars tags that link to some of the objects properties (`{{myProperty}}`),so when the object is emptied or every property set to `""` or `null`, this binding should still exist if the properties are updated to new values.

Is there a way to achieve this? Is there a way to maybe loop through all the properties quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work for your application to use an `{{#if}}` statement in the template to conditionally show/hide your properties?

**Like this:**

```
{{#if view.showStuff }}
    <p>{{view.myProperty1}}</p>
    <p>{{view.myProperty2}}</p>
    <p>{{view.myProperty3}}</p>
{{else}}
    <p>Not showing content</p>
{{/if}}
```

If `showStuff` is true then your properties will be rendered, otherwise it will display the other html.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/rHafx/1/

Answer (score 4):

(started writing this thinking that `eachAttribute` is a method on `Ember.Object`, but it's on `DS.Model` instead. So...)

If your object happens to be an Ember Data `DS.Model` instance, there is the `eachAttribute` method, which takes a callback function. So one way to do what you're suggesting might be:

```
modelobj.eachAttribute(function(propName){
    modelobj.set(propName, null);
});
```

The only other idea that springs to mind is instantiating a new "blank" instance of your object, and assigning it in the old one's place...I *think* handlebars bindings would update properly in most cases if you did that.

Comment: Actually, I did a 'set("property",null)', on a 'belongsTo' property, and then was getting an 'x undefined' error in a subsequent 'this.get("list.@each.property").forEach(function(x) { ...do something with x... })'.  So, I don't think this is quite the right answer.